PandasのDataFrameにおける各列の最終行を削除したい
PandasのDataFrameにおける各列の最終行を削除する方法についてです。
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,Nan], 'B': [4,5,6,7], 'C' : [8,9,Nan,Nan]}

のようなDataFrameで、各列の最後の値である、3,7,9を除去した新たなDataFrameを作製したいです。
あまり慣れておらずうまく質問の文章が書けていませんが、良い方法があれば何卒ご教示のほどお願いいたします。
追記: DataFrameの要素数について修正しました。実際は上記のようにNanが入っており、Nanの一つ上の値をそれぞれ削除したいという意図の質問です。大変失礼しました。

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6,7], 'C': [8,9]} を実行すると ValueError が発生します。ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length エラーメッセージにある通り、各列の要素数が異なることが原因です。

この記事 Pandas　データフレーム　欠損値がある行の確認 を応用して各列の最初のNaNの行位置(やインデックス)を取得し、その一つ上の値にNaNを代入すれば良いのでは？

削除ではなく、np.nan に入れ換えます。
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,np.nan], 'B': [4,5,6,7], 'C': [8,9,np.nan,np.nan]})
for i, j in df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index).items():
    df.loc[j, i] = np.nan

print(df)

#      A    B    C
# 0  1.0  4.0  8.0
# 1  2.0  5.0  NaN
# 2  NaN  6.0  NaN
# 3  NaN  NaN  NaN

ここで、全ての列データが nan である行を削除したい場合は以下の様にします。
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
print(df)

#      A    B    C
# 0  1.0  4.0  8.0
# 1  2.0  5.0  NaN
# 2  NaN  6.0  NaN

